# Getting propery on an object containing in String variable

Tags: groovy, properties

For example I've an object,

```
somethingObject
```

I can get value from the above object as

```
somethingObject.property1.property2
```

if I've the property in variable as
 `String property = "prperty1.property2"`
then How I can access the `property` by using variable on an object `somethingObject`.
any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: In Java you need to use *reflection API* for this but I'd stronly discurage and suggest that you review your design!

Comment: You can use the (rather outdated and somewhat unpleasant to use) [Apache Commons BeanUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/), you would write something like [`PropertyUtils.getNestedProperty(somethingObject, "property1.property2")`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/javadocs/v1.9.3/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/PropertyUtils.html#getNestedProperty-java.lang.Object-java.lang.String-). This of course assumes that you have correctly named accessors. Otherwise, it's trivial with a bit of [reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/).

Answer (score 0):

Either use

```
somethingObject.'property1.property2'
```

or

```
somethingObject."$property"
```

or

```
somethingObject[property]
```